# How do I type a Response object from a fetch request?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I'm running parallel requests for a series of fetches. I want to type `results` as an array of response objects (instead of array of type `any`) but I'm unsure of how to do this. I googled "how to type response object in Typescript" but didn't get useful hits. Is there a way to type the response object other than manually creating a custom type that has all the properties on a response object? Does Typescript have a special built in type we could use here?

```html
const results: any = [];

fetch(URL, {
  headers: {
    ...
  }
})
  .then(response => {
    results.push(response);
  })
  .catch(err => {
    ...
  })
  
const responses = await Promise.all(results);
return responses;
```

Comment: Have you tried `Response[]`?

Comment: You are passing an empty array to `Promise.all`. Before asking how to type this, maybe you'd first need to fix the script.

Comment: There is no generic implementation in Response type. I usually define my own function with generics and return type. and use fetch inside the function.

Comment: @trincot It is implied that responses are being pushed in the first .then() block. Please read more carefully.

Comment: @earthseed, be sure I read carefully, but the array is empty at the moment `Promise.all` executes. The `then` callback executes *later* ... too late. But maybe you didn't represent your real code correctly?

Answer (score 0):

Since I am using `node-fetch`, I ended up with the following solution.
https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-fetch#class-response

```
import { Response } from 'node-fetch';

const results: Response[] = [];

fetch(URL, {
  headers: {
    ...
  }
})
  .then(response => {
    results.push(response);
  })
  .catch(err => {
    ...
  })
  
const responses = await Promise.all(results);
return responses;
```